# What is the size of this angle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> [image: diagram]
>
> The diagram shows two circles, centres $A$ and $B$, each of radius $10 \text{cm}$. The point $B$ lies on the circumference of the circle with centre $A$. The two circles intersect at the points $C$ and $D$. The point $E$ lies on the circumference of the circle centre $B$ such that $ABE$ is a diameter.
>
> Write down, in terms of $\pi$, angle $CBE$.
>
> ***Note:** when trying to reproduce the diagram, I forgot to put a line segment between $A$ and $C$.*

I tried to solve this question but got the answer wrong:

$\triangle ABC \text{ is an equilateral triangle since all of its sides are equal in length}$

\begin{align}
\angle ABC &= \frac{360^\circ}{3} \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{3} \\
\\
\angle CBE &= 180^\circ - \angle ABC \\
&= \pi - \frac{2\pi}{3} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{3} \text{rad}
\end{align}

My answer, $\frac{\pi}{3} \text{rad}$, was incorrect.

The correct answer was $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

How and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that each angle of an equilateral triangle is equal to $60^\circ=\frac \pi3$. This can be seen by drawing equilateral triangles in a circle. You can draw $6$ of them, not $3$.
Then, the rest is similar to what you did.